# Web API endpoints on the same Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am having a working Web API application which has the controller called `StudyDataController` which accepts the input parameters, queries Database and returns result in JSON.That piece is working fine. Calling `http://localhost:3214/api/StudyDataController?param1=R01&param2=05-NOV-16` returns result.

```
public class StudyDataController : ApiController
{  [HttpGet]
   public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails(string param1, DateTime param2)
    {
            List<OracleParameter> p = new List<OracleParameter>();
            p.Add(new OracleParameter("param1", OracleDbType.Varchar2,param1, ParameterDirection.Input));
            p.Add(new OracleParameter("param2",OracleDbType.Date,param2, ParameterDirection.Input));
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StudyDataConnection"].ConnectionString;
            using (OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
            {
                DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
                var strQuery = "SELECT * from Studydata_VW where Request_id = :param1 and RequestDate > :param2 ";
                var returnObject = new { data = new OracleDataTableJsonResponse(connStr, strQuery, prms.ToArray()) };
                var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnObject, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
                ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
                if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=StudyData.json", out contentDisposition))
                {
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
                }
                return response;
               }}}
```

But I now need to create a one more API has different input parameters and query is different and returns result in JSON. For this I am trying to create one Controller called `StudyDatawithDateController` on the same application.

```
public class StudyDatawithDateController : ApiController
{  [HttpGet]
   public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails(DateTime param1,String param2)
    {
            List<OracleParameter> p = new List<OracleParameter>();
            p.Add(new OracleParameter("param1",OracleDbType.Date,param1, ParameterDirection.Input));
            p.Add(new OracleParameter("param2", OracleDbType.Varchar2,param2, ParameterDirection.Input));

            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StudyDataConnection"].ConnectionString;
            using (OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
            {
                DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
                var strQuery = "SELECT * from Studydata_VW where Submit_date> :param1 and Status = :param2 ";
                var returnObject = new { data = new OracleDataTableJsonResponse(connStr, strQuery, prms.ToArray()) };
                var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnObject, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
                ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
                if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=StudyDatawithDate.json", out contentDisposition))
                {
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
                }
                return response;
               }}}
```

If I try to call the endpoint like `http://localhost:3214/api/StudyDatawithDateController?param1=01-NOV-16&param2=COMPLETE` it says `Not Found Error`. 
[image]

The webConfig.cs is like below

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
 {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Can we have two controllers on the same WebAPI application. Most of the questions/Samples are discussing about having same name controllers. But here I am having different names and how can I deal with this.

Comment: You can have as many controller as you want. Did you forget to add the http method attribute? You need to post your code.

Comment: Probably yes. bou're probaby going to have to clarify your question. Maybe some code

Comment: @Marco I have edited the question. Can you please tell me what I am missing here

Comment: @YounElan I have edited the question. Can you please tell me what I am missing here

Comment: your url is `StudyDatController` missing an `a`?

Comment: you mention calling `http://localhost:3214/api/StudyDatController?param1=01-NOV-16&param2=COMPLETE` to access your second method - if you want to call the method in `StudyDatawithDateController` then surely the URL should be `http://localhost:3214/api/StudyDataWithDateController?param1=01-NOV-16&param2=COMPLETE` ?

Comment: @ADyson That was Typo mistake here while copy paste I will correct them in the question

Comment: @abdul it was typo here while copy pasting I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have many routes using get request going to one and the same Controller but different actions with different attribute routes. Just add attribute routing on top of the method you want the route to process

[HttpGet]
//http://localhost:3214/api/StudyDatawithDateController?param1=01-NOV-16&param2=COMPLETE
[Route("api/StudyDatawithDateController/param1/{param1:string}/param2/{param2:string"})]

http://localhost:3214/api/StudyDataController?param1=R01&param2=05-NOV-16
[Route("api/StudyDataController/param1/{param1:string}/param2/{param2:string")]

The example above will still not work. but if you change the url - specifically param2 and param1 - give them some descriptive names and in the endpoints you will have different parameters.

param2 in the second example is Date and in the first string saying COMPLATE. - change that add the attribute routes and you will be fine.

Comment: I dont understand about iscomplate

Comment: it is just example parameter based on COMPLETE in [HttpGet] //http://localhost:3214/api/StudyDatawithDateController?param1=01-NOV-16&param2=COMPLETE Looking at it now I made a mistake defining the example routes will change it now

Comment: Not sure this entirely makes sense. You say "You can have many routes using get request going to one and the same Controller" but then give examples of URLs which go to two different controllers. Correct me if I'm wrong but with the examples as given I don't think you need the Route attributes.

Comment: @trx TBH I can't see why your code doesn't work as it currently exists. There are two different controllers, with different GET methods, the default route config is in use and the method names match the normal conventions in Web API 2, but the second one appears not to work. It doesn't seem to me like routing is the issue. I feel like something else is going on. It would be useful if you would share the exact HTTP status code which is returned when you attempt to make the request, and/or any exception which is generated by the API.

Comment: @ADyson I tried cecking in the fiddler and the error I am getting is {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:3214/api/StudyDataWithDate?param1‌​=01-NOV-16&param2=CO‌​MPLETE'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'StudyDataWithDate'."}

Comment: and you are definitely sending via GET, not POST or any other method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128859/discussion-between-trx-and-adyson).

Comment: @LyubomirVelchev Adding the Route as you suggested is not working.

Comment: @trx can you give example of the request you tried? URL with parameters? should be http://localhost:3214/api/StudyDataController/param1/R01/param2/05-NOV-16 to work Check Attribute Routing topics for WebAPI and see how to change it to your example.